# Launching one script from another is not working

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to automate a copy and rename function when I plug in my Doxie Go scanner.  To detect when I connect the device to my machine I am using the following script: https://superuser.com/questions/219401/starting-scheduled-task-by-detecting-connection-of-usb-device

```
#Requires -version 2.0
Register-WmiEvent -Class win32_VolumeChangeEvent -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
Write-Host (Get-Date -format s) " Beginning script..."

do 
{
    $newEvent = Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
    $eventType = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.EventType

    $eventTypeName = switch($eventType)
    {
        1 {"Configuration changed"}
        2 {"Device arrival"}
        3 {"Device removal"}
        4 {"docking"}
    }

    Write-Host (Get-Date -format s) " Event detected = " $eventTypeName

    if ($eventType -eq 2)
    {
        $driveLetter = $newEvent.SourceEventArgs.NewEvent.DriveName
        $driveLabel = ([WMI]"Win32_LogicalDisk='$driveLetter'").VolumeName
        Write-Host (Get-Date -format s) " Drive name = " $driveLetter
        Write-Host (Get-Date -format s) " Drive label = " $driveLabel

        # Execute process if drive matches specified condition(s)
        if ($driveLabel -eq 'DOXIE')
        {
            Write-Host (Get-Date -format s) " Starting task in 3 seconds..."
            Start-Sleep -seconds 3
            Start-Process -FilePath "D:\My Archives\Automation\PowerShell\Batch Move and Rename for Google Cloud.ps1"

        }
    }

    Remove-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange

} 
while (1-eq1) #Loop until next event

Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier volumeChange
```

This works as intended.  The issue I'm running into is this line of code:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "D:\My Archives\Automation\PowerShell\Batch Move and Rename for Google Cloud.ps1"
```

When running this line a PowerShell window opens for a split second then immediately closes.  I know the script takes longer than that to run, especially when there are hundreds of documents on the scanner. Separately, the called script works fine.

I'm on Windows 10 with PowerShell v5.1.14393.693. Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console is probably showing an error before exiting. The usual suspect is that your execution policy doesn't allow script execution etc., which you can bypass with `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass` (unless policy is set by GPO).

Try launching it with `-NoExit` to make the console stay open so you can see if there's an error.

```
Start-Process -FilePath powershell -ArgumentList "-NoExit", "-File", "D:\My Archives\Automation\PowerShell\Batch Move and Rename for Google Cloud.ps1"
```

Also, you should always specify `powershell` as the process when launching a script as a new process. `ps1` is by default opened in Notepad when called by filename (or double clicked).

Comment: Thank you for the assist!  I was able to make it work using single quotes around the arguments, and double quotes around the script name:

Start-Process -FilePath powershell -ArgumentList 'ExecutionPolicy Bypass', '-File "D:\My Archives\Automation\PowerShell\Batch Move and Rename for Google Cloud.ps1"'